# Generating DDL (specific to postgres) Scripts Conditionally

Tags: postgresql, preprocessor, m4

My application does not fit into the "general purpose" RDBMS schema category, I do not want a ginormous DDL script -- therefore I would need `#include` semantics and I will probably have different variants of the scripts therefore I would need `#ifdef` semantics.

Is GNU m4 the way to go?

Or perhaps there are some macro capabilities in `psql`?

edit: After a while of working with m4 it seems to fit the bill, I have answered the question below (won't accept for a while), but if you feel you can add more to this question please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes m4 is a suitable tool for this particular style of coding -- remember though: don't go overboard with adding too many macros.

As the manual [states](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Intro) m4 is addictive, so be careful.